# Update python dictionary value with new list using loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary, I need to update dictionary value with list according to existing key.

existing dictionary

```
zone = {
'a':11,
'b':22,
'c':12
}
```

New list

```
list_ = (10, 44, 55)
```

I need to update that dictionary using this list

I need dictionary like this:

```
zone = {
'a':10,
'b':44,
'c':55
}
```

Comment: You are using an ordered dictionary? (Python 3.7 or special type)

Comment: I'm using unordered dictionary in python 3.4

Comment: @ZahidUanNabi How do you know which value in the tuple matches to which key in the dict?

Comment: Then how to you plan to map the values from the list to the keys of the dictionary?

Comment: I need to update first list item to first key value , so far ...

Comment: @ZahidUanNabi If you're using unordered dicts, there's no such thing as the "first key value". Or rather, the first key value (as returned by, e.g., `zone.keys()`) will be effectively random. There's no way around that unless you can refactor the code to define `zone` as an OrderedDict or similar. If you want to assign to the keys in alphabetical (or some other sorted) order, that's doable, but we don't know if that's what you're trying to do unless you say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Dictionary does not have the order. So, You can not set sequentially without the standard of ordering. But, You do this if you want to set by the order of dictionary keys. Please refer as below:

```
zone = {'b':22, 'a':11, 'c':12}
data = (10, 44, 55)

z_ordered = list(zone.keys())
z_ordered.sort()

for index in range(len(z_ordered)):
    zone[z_ordered[index]] = data[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get keys from the zone and `zip` it with the list and convert result to a `dict`

```
zone = {'a':11, 'b':22, 'c':12 }
list_ = [10, 44, 55]

zone = dict(zip((*zone,), list_))

#{'a': 10, 'b': 44, 'c': 55}
```